# In which situation a view does not overlap another view?

Tags: android, xml, layout

As you may know if one tag come after another tag in xml the last one can overlap the first one.
as you can see in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button ONE"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button TWO"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but this rule wouldn't apply if the first view have elevation (however I just tested it by TabLayout).
here is example of not overlapping first view because of elevation attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#09A536"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="453dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#D0021B"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However I don't now what is the reason behind this.

Comment: why is this minus for?

Comment: Which minus? Please make sure to tag a user with "@" or write under the answer if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in [Material Design docs](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design):

> Elevation is the relative distance between two surfaces along the z-axis.

So when you are thinking about that you should imagine a 3D space like that:

[image: Elevation Material Design]

When you are applying elevation you are basically pushing one View up over another, or elevating it.